# How does the area of illumination affect the numerical aperture / optical resolution of an optical system?

Tags: optics, visible-light, imaging

I have been reading an optics paper in which they designed a microscope with the following setup.  A light source passes through a small pinhole, illuminates a sample, which then forms a diffraction pattern on the detector (in this case, a hologram, but this is irrelevant).

[image: Inline holography]

Now let's say that distance between the sample and the detector is $z$, and the width of the sensor is $w$.  Now, the authors claim that the NA of the system is defined by:

$NA = \frac {w/2}{\sqrt {(w/2)^2 + z^2}} $

This comes from the formula from numerical aperture, $NA = n sin(\theta) $, where they have assumed $n=1$ for the refractive index of air and $tan(\theta) \approx sin(\theta)$ for small angles.

Now, this makes sense, except in the paper, the illumination source does not illuminate the entire detector (or barely illuminates it because the light spot is not larger enough to cover the entire detector).  If there is no light or very little light illuminating the outer area of the sensor, can they still claim the above formula for numerical aperture?

If we only record a region of interest (say, the center part of the detector) and leave the rest of the system unchanged, will we see a reduction in numerical aperture or optical resolution?